# How do I display certain values in this query? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    grade, SNAME
FROM  
    Grade_report 
JOIN 
    Student ON Grade_report.student_number = Student.stno
WHERE 
    grade LIKE '[a-b]'
```

I need to display the students who has received more than one A or B. What should I add?

Comment: Perhaps a count, what db engine are you using?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: I used jQuery as a keyword by mistake, I apologize I'm new to this site.

Comment: @Mathemats i'm using management studio

Comment: You need to use count, and also the 'having' keyword

Comment: @pala_ can you show me what the syntax should be? I'm new to this software and am just learning.

Comment: i haven't really used sql server, but try here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Answer (score 0):

I just created some sample data here, but your answer requires the HAVING keyword.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

In this case John is the only result as he received both an A and a B.

```
DECLARE @temptable AS TABLE 
            (CLASS int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
            SNAME varchar(20),
            GRADE char(1));

        INSERT INTO @temptable(SNAME,GRADE)
        VALUES ('John','A'),('Jack','B'),('John','B'),('Jack','C'),('Jill','D');


        SELECT * FROM @temptable

        --This is your answer
        SELECT SNAME,COUNT(*)
        FROM @temptable
        WHERE GRADE IN ('A','B')
        GROUP BY SNAME
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```